# Symfony 5 - internationalized routes - Prefix routes with locale

Tags: routes, internationalization, symfony4, symfony5

How can we automaticaly prefix routes paths in symfony5 with locales ?

```
# file: config/routes.yaml

index_blog:
  path:
    en: blog/homepage
    fr: blog/accueil
  controller: App\Controller\HomepageController::index
```

When we debug we have something like this

```
php bin/console debug:router


  index_blog.en              ANY      ANY      ANY    /blog/homepage
  index_blog.fr              ANY      ANY      ANY    /blog/accueil
```

So what should we do to prefix url with _locale to have something like

```
/**fr**/blog/accueil
/**en**/blog/homepage
```

JMSI18nRoutingBundle is not working for Symfony 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution i found :

```
# file: config/routes.yaml

my_app:
  prefix:
    fr: /fr
    en: /en
    es: /es
  resource: '../src/App/Resources/config/routes/routing.yaml'
  name_prefix: app_web_
#  defaults:
#    subdomain: www
#    domain: localhost.com
#  host: "{subdomain}.{domain}"
#  requirements:
#    domain: (localhost.com|localhost.org)
```

And if you want to always redirect to preferred route "/fr" if "/" you must add an event subscriber.

See Symfony Demo App.